# Git workflow: merging branches while avoiding repetitive commit messages

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

I am doing some SCSS refactoring on a project with lots of SCSS files.

**Here is my approach: to create a new branch for each SCSS file refactor.**

For example, I create a new branch called `scss-lint-refactor-chicken` and checkout to it, I complete the refactor (which would involve `Chicken.jsx` and `Chicken.scss` and possibly some other files) and commit the changes.

Then, I checkout to master, and merge the branch.

The master branch ends up with a history like this:

```
*   75d48b2 - (7 minutes ago) Merge branch 'scss-lint-refactor-chicken' - Rory Smith
|\  
| * 9ea664f - (9 minutes ago) SCSS lint refactor chicken - Rory Smith
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a good approach to workflow for version control for such a job?
2. How can I optimise the process so that I don't get 2 commit messages that essentially say the same thing in different ways?

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is _rebase_. See [merging vs. rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is a good way to use a version control system, so you can leave your work behind or have two or more commits for the same refactoring.
2. Do not fear the merge messages. They are your friend. Git won't be slower because you have a few more commits. If you think they pollute your git log too much, hide them :

   ```
   git log --no-merges
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

You can run `git rebase master` when you are on your branch and then run `git merge <branch>` from your `master` branch. This will remove the `merge` commit and might make the commit history a bit cleaner.